# How to Create an un-ordered tree in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

Is there a way to create a tree in LaTeX without using any "ordering" ? 
So far, all the examples I came across are structured in this way

```
child{ node [arn_n] {20}
                        child{ node [arn_r] {18}}
                        child{ node [arn_x] {}}
        }
```

Where the parent knows in advance his children, In my case I would generate this LaTeX code from a Python script, going through some data, and the children are not known until actually found in the data.

So  What I am looking for is some sort of library that would allow me to list all my nodes, and each node would only know his parent.

```
 child 0  parent 0
 child 1  parent 0
 child 2  parent 0
 child 3  parent 1
```

and then my tree would be generated accordingly in LaTeX. Unfortunately I have not found any examples yet or if this was possible.

Thank you.

Comment: How about GraphiViz? There are packages to integrate in LaTeX.

Comment: Well, that should work ``{rankdir=RL; a->b; b->c; b->d}`` i'll give it a try right now.

Comment: I once created a simple script to run Graphviz from LaTeX via write18, I can post that if you like. You can even simplify your work if you put your structure into Excel or any other spreadsheet application and have it generate the code you need.

Comment: No that's fine, GraphViz actually works pretty well, I now have to look how to have the tree overlapping two pages, in case it is bigger than expected.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) program has packages for drawing trees. They are announced as examples/tests, but work well enough for use in anger.

Comment: Thank you actually graphViz did exactly what I intended to do.

Comment: @noktec Can you post an answer so others can benefit from your question, too? Nothing more frustrating than comments which say what a great solution somebody's found with only the vaguest hints as to what that great solution is ;).

Comment: Or maybe @UweZiegenhagen could answer if that would be preferable/fairer?

Comment: @cfr I just provided an introductory example, tell me if you wish to know more.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen Thanks. This is not something I have any idea about but it looks interesting :).

Answer (score 3):

Okay, here's a very introductory example.

Let's assume we have the following table in Excel, showing the children and their parents:

[image: Excel]

The third column uses a formula to concatenate the two columns together and to add the " -> " , required for the GraphViz Syntax.

Next we can create a simple text file in an editor and copy/paste the generated code into the following template:

```
digraph G{

<generated code>

}
```

result:

```
digraph G{
child0 -> parent0
child1 -> parent0
child2 -> parent0
child3 -> parent1
}
```

(Of course the generation of code file and even it's compilation by `dot` could be integrated into Excel.) This file is saved under `tsx.dot`. Next I call GraphViz's `dot` engine to convert the graph into PDF:

```
dot -Tpdf tsx.dot > tsx.pdf
```

tsx.pdf then looks like the following:

[image]

GraphViz is pretty powerful, this of course may make the Excel and the required formulas pretty complex (for example, if different node styles are to be used)

There are packages which integrate dot into LaTeX, however I prefer a 'selfmade' LaTeX snippet which allows me to save arbitrary code from a LaTeX environment into an external file and run a batch program on it (Currently I use it for GraphViz and Python). I'll write a blog post on this later this week.